# Cannot assign "2022": "Profile.year_of_passing" must be a "Batch" instance

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, foreign-keys

This is my model.py file

```
from asyncio import constants
import profile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime, os
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from model_utils import FieldTracker
from time import strftime
from applications.adminportal.mail_helper import send_verification_email


class Constants:
    SEX_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
        ('O', 'Other')
    )

    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        ('S','Student'),
        ('A','Alumni'),
    )

    PROG_CHOICES = (
        ('B.Tech', 'B.Tech'),
        ('B.Des', 'B.Des'),
        ('M.Des', 'M.Des'),
        ('M.Tech', 'M.Tech'),
        ('PhD', 'PhD')
    )

    BRANCH = (
        ('CSE', 'Computer Science and Engineering'),
        ('ECE', 'Electronics and Communication Engineering'),
        ('ME', 'Mechanical Engineering'),
        ('SM', 'Smart Manufacturing'),
        ('NS', 'Natural Sciences'),
        ('MT', 'Mechatronics'),
        ('DS', 'Design'),
        ('NA', 'Not Applicable')
    )

    WORKING_STATUS = (
        ('Is Working', 'Is Working'),
        ('Is Pursuing Higher Studies', 'Is Pursuing Higher Studies'),
        ('Is Self Employed', 'Is Self Employed')
    )

    EMPLOYMENT_TYPE = (
        ('ft', 'Full-time'),
        ('pt', 'Part-time'),
        ('se', 'Self-employed'),
        ('fr', 'Freelance'),
        ('in', 'Internship'),
        ('tr', 'Trainee'),
    )
`your text`
    
    YEAR_OF_ADDMISSION = tuple((n, str(n)) for n in range(2005, datetime.datetime.now().year))

   
    ADMISSION_YEAR = tuple((n, str(n)) for n in range(1990, datetime.datetime.now().year + 1))

    PASSING_YEAR = tuple((n, str(n)) for n in range(2005, datetime.datetime.now().year))


class Batch(models.Model):
    year_of_passing = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.year_of_passing


def upload_photo(instance, filename):
    name, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    return 'Profile_Pictures/' + str(instance.roll_no) + ".jpg"


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=Constants.ROLE_CHOICES, default='A')
    # Institute Details
    roll_no = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=15)
    year_of_admission = models.IntegerField(null=True, choices=Constants.YEAR_OF_ADDMISSION)
    
    year_of_passing = models.ForeignKey(Batch, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,choices=Constants.PASSING_YEAR)
    programme = models.CharField(max_length=1000, choices=Constants.PROG_CHOICES, null=False)
    branch = models.CharField(choices=Constants.BRANCH, max_length=1000, null=False)

    # Alumni Specific
    reg_no = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, default=0, editable=False)

    # Personal Details
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="", null=False)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=Constants.SEX_CHOICES, default='M')
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(default=datetime.date(1970, 1, 1))
    email = models.EmailField()
    alternate_email = models.EmailField()
    fathers_name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="")
    spouse_name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=1000, default="")
    mobile1 = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)
    mobile2 = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    phone_no = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    current_address = models.TextField(max_length=1000, default="")
    permanent_address = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=1000, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=1000, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=1000, blank=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to=upload_photo)

    # Experience & Higher Studies (for Alumni)
    working_status = models.CharField(max_length=1000, choices=Constants.WORKING_STATUS, blank=True)
    current_position = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    current_organisation = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_joining = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default=datetime.date.today)
    past_experience = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    current_course = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=1000)
    current_university = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=1000)

    # Social
    linkedin = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True, default="www.linkedin.com")
    facebook = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True, default="www.facebook.com")
    instagram = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=1000)
    website = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    # User verification
    mail_sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # To be used to track if the email was actually sent.
    verify = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    mail_sent_tracker = FieldTracker(fields=['verify'])

    # Last edit
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


@receiver(post_save, sender=Profile)
def check(sender, instance, created, update_fields, **kwargs):
    if instance.mail_sent_tracker.has_changed('verify') and instance.mail_sent_tracker.previous(
            'verify') != True:  # Alumni Verified
        mail_sent = send_verification_email("alumni.iiitdmj.ac.in", True, instance)

        # Can use either of below methods.
        # Though, the bottom one is preferred.
        # sender.objects.filter(roll_no=instance.roll_no).update(mail_sent=mail_sent)

        post_save.disconnect(check, Profile)
        instance.mail_sent = mail_sent
        instance.save()
        post_save.connect(check, Profile)


class PastExperience(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    emp_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Constants.EMPLOYMENT_TYPE)
    organisation = models.CharField(verbose_name='Company/Org name', max_length=1000)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)


class Degree(models.Model):
    """For Education model."""
    degree = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.degree)


class Education(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    degree = models.ForeignKey(Degree, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    discipline = models.CharField(verbose_name='Discipline/Field', max_length=200)
    institute = models.CharField(verbose_name='Institute Name', max_length=1000)
    admission_year = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    passing_year = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.profile.name} - {self.institute}'
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Constants, Degree, Education, Profile, PastExperience , Batch
from datetime import datetime

try:
    from collections.abc import defaultdict
except ImportError:
    from collections import defaultdict


#
# Create your views here.

# @login_required
def profile(request, username):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user__username=username)
    current_experiences = PastExperience.objects.filter(profile=profile, end_date=None).order_by('-start_date')
    experiences = PastExperience.objects.filter(profile=profile, end_date__isnull=False).order_by('-end_date', '-start_date')
    current_education = Education.objects.filter(profile=profile, passing_year=None).order_by('-admission_year')
    education = Education.objects.filter(profile=profile, passing_year__isnull=False).order_by('-passing_year', '-admission_year')

    profile.roll_no = str(profile.roll_no)
    profile = vars(profile)

    # Add experience
    profile.update({
        'current_experiences': current_experiences,
        'experiences': experiences,
        'EMPLOYMENT_TYPE': Constants.EMPLOYMENT_TYPE,
    })
    
    # Add education
    profile.update({
        'current_education': current_education,
        'education': education,
        'ADMISSION_YEAR': Constants.ADMISSION_YEAR,
        'PASSING_YEAR': Constants.PASSING_YEAR,
        'DEGREE': list(Degree.objects.all().order_by('degree')),
    })

    return render(request, "alumniprofile/profile.html", profile)


def index(request):
    years = set(Profile.objects.all().values_list('batch', flat=True))
    print(years)
    return render(request, "alumniprofile/index.html", {'years': years})


def index_year(request, year):
    alumni = Profile.objects.filter(batch=year)
    
    return render(request, "alumniprofile/index_year.html", {'alumni': alumni})



def add_experience(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)

    if request.method == "POST":
        position = request.POST.get('position')
        emp_type = request.POST.get('emp_type')
        organisation = request.POST.get('organisation')
        start_date = request.POST.get('start_date')
        end_date = request.POST.get('end_date') or None

        PastExperience.objects.create(profile=profile, position=position, emp_type=emp_type, organisation=organisation, start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)

    return redirect('profile:profile', request.user.username)

def add_education(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)

    if request.method == "POST":
        degree_val = request.POST.get('degree_select')
        if request.POST.get('degree_not_listed'):
            degree_val = request.POST.get('degree_input')

        degree = Degree.objects.filter(degree=degree_val).first()
        if not degree:
            degree = Degree(degree=degree_val)
            degree.save()
        discipline =request.POST.get('discipline')
        institute =request.POST.get('institute')
        admission_year =request.POST.get('admission_year')
        passing_year =request.POST.get('passing_year') or None

        Education.objects.create(profile=profile, degree=degree, discipline=discipline, institute=institute, admission_year=admission_year, passing_year=passing_year)

    return redirect('profile:profile', request.user.username)
```

so while taking input from user
when i hit submit
i get this error
`Cannot assign "2022": "Profile.year_of_passing" must be a "Batch" instance`

there is an issue with assigning the value "2022" to the year_of_passing field in the Profile model. The field year_of_passing expects an instance of the Batch model, but you are providing an integer value instead.

Actually i am new to Django
i tried some solutions but they didnt worked

please tell whats wrong in the code
and why i am getting this error
how should i solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a `ForeignKey`, you assign this as:

```
my_profile.year_of_passing_id = 2022
```

but this will only work if there is already such `Batch` object with that primary key.

You can create one with:

```
my_profile.year_of_passing, __ = Batch.objects.get_or_create(year_of_passing=2022)
```

It is however not entirely clear to me why you made a `Batch` model in the first place, given it only stores a year. Why not use an `IntegerField` in the `Profile` for `year_of_passing`? If you want to do proper validation, you could make a subclass of `IntegerField` like `YearField` that does some extra validation, but a `ForeignKey` here looks "*odd*", and will likely, due to lack of [**`.select_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) use, eventually result in *N+1 problems*.

Comment: I tried this but this isnt working too please tell me another solution 
actually i want to use the `year_of_passing` to another table for student chapter
do you need any other information regarding these ?

Comment: @PrathameshShinde: please share the view where you do this. It makes not much sense to use the table somewhere else, since the table is only that: an `IntegerField`...

Comment: added the views in edited question can you take a look at it ?

Comment: @PrathameshShinde: `Education.objects.create(..., passing_year_id=passing_year)` or thus the "trick" with `get_or_create`. But using `request.POST` directly and not passing it through a form is often a precursor for flawed security...

Comment: can you show me by doing changes in code i provided 
cause i tried this also maybe im doing it wrong